# How to select distinct value from one column only

Tags: mysql

I have records as follows:

```
key  | name
--------------
1111 | aa   
1111 | bb    
2222 | cc
```

I need to select the `key` and `name` when the `key` value is distinct. When I tried:

```
select distinct key, name from table;
```

I got all the rows since the query takes distinct for the combination of the columns: `key` and `name`. But, what I need is only distinct `key` and I don't care about the `name`. I have a lot of records, so I need a practical method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT `key`, MAX(`name`) as name
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `key`
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
SELECT distinct key
FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT key, name
FROM table
GROUP BY key
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT key, name FROM table GROUP BY key;
```

This returns one row for each distinct value of `key`, and the value of `name` is arbitrarily chosen from the rows in that group.  In practice, MySQL tends to return the value of name from the row physically stored first in the group, but that's not guaranteed.

As other answers show, you can put name into an aggregate expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about not groupped fields try this query -

```
select key, name from table group by key order by name
```

MySQL lets selecting fields without using aggregate function.

*order by name* helps to select first name from the group.

Comment: I believe this is invalid SQL, altough MySQL accepts it and returns something. Also this "something" is a random name from the set of names having the same key, therefore the result is not deterministic (depending on table deletions and inserts). This makes no sense and encourages misunderstanding among those that do not already grasp the concept of aggregation.

Comment: I cannot say it is invalid. MySQL allows it, and we can use it. I agree about random record; there should be aggregate function, or ORDER BY clause - which will help to select exact value. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It is invalid per ANSI/ISO SQL, since it results in an ambiguous result.  MySQL and SQLite are the only RDBMS implementations that permit this form, as far as I know.  Other RDBMS products return an error.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * from table group by key having count(key) = 1
```